# Fixed header and footer in android app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I want to use fixed header and footer in my android app, but every time a new activity starts, the page refreshes and both the header and footer reload.
How can I make them fixed through out the application life cycle so that they never reload, although I can hide, remove and add items to them?

I've used the include tag and it's not what I want

Comment: Please show your layout file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use one Activity with header, footer and the content Fragment. Instead of starting new Activity, you'll change the content Fragment.

**But.** This is not expected neither by Android nor by user. Also you need some kind of Back button handling, state saving/restoring and so on. Are you sure that you want to do what you described?

If so, here are some useful links:

- [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html);
- [Building a Dynamic UI with Fragments](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html);
- [Add a Fragment to an Activity at Runtime](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html#AddAtRuntime);
- [FragmentTransaction](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html) - for custom transaction animation see setTransition() and setCustomAnimations() methods.

Also if you want to use fragments on Android prior 3.0 (API level 11), you'll need the [Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html)
For custom transit animation

Comment: yeah, this is exactly what I want to achieve. How do I proceed?

Comment: I've added some links to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here what give you is the sample example how to have a fixed header and footer all over the [application](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/10/android-header-and-footer-layout-example.html)

Comment: this is exactly what i did, but not what i want. Like I said, after launching a new activity the entire layout reloads, which I don't want. I want all the layouts to be inflated between the header and footer.

Answer (score 0):

You can  consider this  [example](http://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/android-header-and-footer-layout-example)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Include tag which can include layout which you want . in every layout of your app just add Include tag as header and footer of your layout