# How to use multiple Fragment in single activity in different times

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am making an app in which the header and footer  would be same through out the app. i can start another activity with the same pattern of design in header and footer but as the other activity starts there comes a delay and we can easily notice that a new activity has pop up.

So what I want :
                 I want that if user click on any button from the footer the content in the middle between header and footer should be change and user should not see any jump which is made when I move to other activity.

So for this I know that I can use fragments. But for some reasons I can not use fragment activity. All I want to move fragment in the center only. So How can i do that . and How can I initialize other things which are in new fragment let say the upcoming fragment could have button so in this way , I wanted to know would it make my main activity heavy which is calling all these fragment

So please guide me through the demo code .

> **Note: please do not refer me to a fragment link just past some code to give me some idea.**

Comment: can you post some code you've tried?

Comment: @KevCron i have not implemented anything different yet, its a same simple activity

Comment: can you post some code you've tried?

Answer (score 0):

Will be easiest to have the activity implement the header and footer and the variable content as fragments.

Please refer to this post. It has everything you need 
[Fixed header and footer in android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20884212/fixed-header-and-footer-in-android-app)